# How to get the return value of a event

Tags: javascript

I use firebug to see the following code,

```
<input type="text" oncut="return false">
```

then try to get the return value of the event oncut,

```
var a=document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
document.write(a.oncut);
```

I want to get the return value of oncut: **false**, however , I get the definition of the function oncut,as follows,

```
function oncut(event){
return false;
}
```

How can I only get the return value "false" from the event oncut?

Comment: if your returned value is constant, then just call the returned function.

Comment: You should explain why you want to have the return value. In this simple case you can just call the function. But a real callback will - in most cases - always use the input event or other data, so calling the function will often fail.

Answer (score 0):

`oncut` in your case is intended as a handler(event handler). `"return false"` is a definition of that handler. To get the returned value from function - just call the function:

```
...
document.write(a.oncut());
...
```

---

For example:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.write(document.getElementsByClassName("cut")[0].oncut());
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class='cut' oncut="return false">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function (giving it an arbitrary name) then add it to the cut event. Place your statement within this function. I used `contentText` instead of `document.write` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/2813224).

```js
function cutFalse() {
  return document.body.textContent = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oncut="cutFalse()">
```

Comment: While I agree that `document.write` should not be used, it might still be _valid_  for short testing (but i would still suggest to always use `console.log`), using `document.body.textContent  = ....;`  is nearly identical to `document.write`.

Comment: In this situation of course the body is the target. I was tempted to add a div to receive the result, but it looked as if the OP objective was to have the result remain in the input's place.